# How to hold the values of controls in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 dropdownlist and 1 table in my Index page. 2nd dropdownlist is populating based on the selection of 1st dropdownlist. Table data will change every time when 2nd dropdown value changes.
Each row in table contains edit button. When I click on edit button it will redirect to another page. After the edit page changes are saved it will be redirected to Index page.

I need to restore the selection, currently I have to select dropdown each time when I'm back in Index page from Edit page. Is there any way to hold the selected value of dropdownlist and table ?
I'm working with ASP.NET Core MVC.

Comment: Maybe you can store this data in some cookie or local storage.

Comment: You have to maintain dropdown value and send back to index page when your are redirecting on index page after save or update.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use cookie to carry a value across pages.

I achieve it in two steps:

**Firstly**, add an `Onchange` event to `<select>`, when you choose an option, the `Onchange` event will set a cookie to save the value which you choose.

**Secondly**, when you load other pages, the `<select>` will read the cookie to show your previous selection.

I write a simple demo to achieve this .Here is my code:

```
<li>
    <select id="fruit" onchange="save(this.value)">
        <option value=0>apple</option>
        <option value=1>pear</option>
        <option value=2>watermelon</option>
        <option value=3>cherry</option>
    </select>
</li>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        //....................set Cookie............
        var saveclass = null;

        function save(cookieValue) {
            var sel = document.getElementById('fruit');
            saveclass = saveclass ? saveclass : document.body.className;
            document.body.className = saveclass + ' ' + sel.value;
            setCookie('theme', cookieValue, 365);
        }

        function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {


            var today = new Date();
            var expire = new Date();

            if (nDays == null || nDays == 0)
                nDays = 1;

            expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
            document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue) + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString() + ";path=/";
        }
        //......................read Cookie.............
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var themeSelect = document.getElementById('fruit');
            var selectedTheme = readCookie('theme');

            themeSelect.value = selectedTheme;
            saveclass = saveclass ? saveclass : document.body.className;
            document.body.className = saveclass + ' ' + selectedTheme;
        });

        function readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }
    </script>
}
```

When you visit the page again ,you can see the page hold the value of dropdown list.

[image]

Comment: If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? Refer to:[How to accept as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks.